# how to properly insert html with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am using this bit of PHP to return a chunk of html:

```
if ($action = "update")
    {

        connect_db();

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM convo ORDER BY date ASC") or die (mysql_error());

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
            $output = $output . '<p>';
            $output = $output . '<b>From:</b> ' .$row['from'];
            $output = $output . ' <b>To:</b> ' .$row['to'];
            $output = $output . ' <b>Message:</b> ' .$row['content'];
            $output = $output . "<br />";
            $output = $output . '</p>';
        }

        //htmlentities($output);

        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode( $output );
    }
```

And then insert it into a `<div>` with this bit of jQuery:

```
function update(){

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "actions.php",
            data: {  
                'action': 'update'
                },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data)
            {
                console.log('update called');
                console.log( data);
                $('#history').text( data );

                //$('#status').text('sent!');
            }
        });             

        setTimeout(update, 5000);
    }
```

The ajax call works and returns the correct html however when inserted it is not formatted, I can see all the html code in the browser. See example picture: [image: browersoutput]

Should be using something other than `.text`?

Comment: Dont use `$output = $output . '<p>';` concatenate with `$output .= '<p>';` and define `$output` above your while loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating JSON in php, and using `json` dataType for no reason when you want html.

Just output the html string in php and remove the `dataType:'json` from AJAX.

```
echo  $output ;
```

Then instert using `html()` method

```
 $('#history').html( data );
```

The `load()` method is ideal for your case. It is a `$.ajax` shortcut method. You could replace all the AJAX you have with:

```
 $('#history').load("actions.php", { 'action': 'update'},function(){
     console.log('new content inserted now')
 })
```

API reference: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: That's fancy. Do I still need to return the data from my php page with `json_encode()` or does it just take the straight html?

Comment: `load` is strictly for html. It will replace the current content of the selector with html from server

Comment: oh  will be a `POST` . If want `GET` can simply change the object I have in data with the string  `"action=update"`..See docs

Answer (score 1):

change `$('#history').text( data );` to `$('#history').html( data );`